# How to use the "cache" in gitlab when trying to use files from two previously run jobs?

Tags: gitlab

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2
  - stage3

job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > data/test1.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - data/test1.txt

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > test2.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - test2.txt

job3:
  stage: stage3
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "job3"
  script:
    - cat data/test1.txt
    - cat test2.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - data/test1.txt
      - test2.txt
```

The plan is to do the following:

1. To run the pipeline with the variable `RUN` not defined, so that ONLY the two jobs `job1` and `job2` are run, but NOT `job3`. The two jobs `job1` and `job2` are supposed to add the files `data/test1.txt` and `test2.txt` to the cache, so they can be fetched later by `job3`.
2. To run the pipeline with the variable `RUN` set to `run3`, which ONLY runs the job `job3`. This job is supposed to fetch the previously generated files from the cache, namely the two files  `data/test1.txt` and `test2.txt`.

**Explanation:**

In reality, the two jobs `job1` and `job2` are very time consuming jobs which also consume a lot of API calls. Therefore, I do not want to rerun them for no reason, as they would generate the same results anyway. I just want to "store" the results from these two jobs `job1` and `job2`, and "fetch" these results from a later running job (maybe a few days later). This `job3` will also run in the same pipeline in the same repo and on the same branch. as the jobs `job1` and `job2`.

**Expected result:**

`job3` can use the two files from the cache created by `job1` and `job2`.

**Observed result**:

```
$ cat data/test1.txt
cat: data/test1.txt: No such file or directory
```

I have the following questions:

1. How can I fix this problem? What IS the problem?
2. Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is the following configuration:

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > data/test1.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - data/test1.txt
      - test2.txt

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > test2.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - data/test1.txt
      - test2.txt

job3:
  stage: stage3
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "job3"
  script:
    - cat data/test1.txt
    - cat test2.txt
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - data/test1.txt
      - test2.txt
```

The documentation says (if you are able to find that particular [statement](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-mismatch-example-1) in the really vast documentation):

> If two jobs have the same cache key but a different path, the caches
> can be overwritten.

So the solution is to use the same "thing" for *each* of the three jobs, so gitlab tries to gull/push the two files all the time.

Answer (score 0):

## According to [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#:%7E:text=Cache%20is%20stored%20where%20GitLab,if%20distributed%20cache%20is%20enabled.&text=Artifacts%20are%20generated%20by%20a,link%20to%20files%20outside%20it.):

Use cache for dependencies, like packages you download from the internet. Cache is stored where GitLab Runner is installed and uploaded to S3 if distributed cache is enabled.

Use artifacts to pass intermediate build results between stages. Artifacts are generated by a job, stored in GitLab, and can be downloaded.

Both artifacts and caches define their paths relative to the project directory, and can’t link to files outside it.

## Solution

I geuss the following will fix it, by adding a default artifacts path to `data` directory. This will store each jobs result in the `data` dir and makes it available in the next job.

For using artifacts from multiple jobs, you should use [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies).

```
default:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./data

stages:
 - stage1
 - stage2
 - stage3

job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > data/test1.txt

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "job3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - date > test2.txt

job3:
  stage: stage3
  dependencies:
    - job1
    - job2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "job3"
  script:
    - cat data/test1.txt
    - cat test2.txt
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not seem to work. I get the same error again: `cat: data/test1.txt: No such file or directory` when I run `job3` after I have run the first two jobs on the same branch.

Comment: Just to be clear: I do two runs of the pipeline. The first run is with the variable `RUN` not set, so that only `job1` and `job2` are executed, but NOT `job`. Then I do another run of the pipeline with the variable `RUN` set to `run3`, which ONLY runs `job3`.

Comment: Ah in case it are different pipeline runs, you have to use the GitLab API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html

Comment: Well, yes, as I tried to explain in the question. But why can't I use a cache? 

In fact, I can use a cache. I answered my own question after about 50 tries on gitlab.